# Can a colon lists out multiple incomplete sentences?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context, punctuation, lists, colons

I raised a similar question [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/349946/10484), but the bulleted list example in [the only answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/349955/10484) to that question confused me, just like this case, as below, I encountered [here](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#service-worker-lifetime):

> A user agent may terminate service workers at any time it:
>
> - Has no event to handle.
> - Detects abnormal operation: such as infinite loops and tasks    exceeding  imposed time limits (if any) while handling the events.

So far as I know, the sentence before the colon is incomplete, and it's followed by a bulleted list containing two incomplete sentences.

Is that snippet correctly punctuated?

Comment: "*at* any time it" is not grammatical.  You can remove "at" and say "any time it" (colloquial) or  "at any time when it" or "whenever it".   Also, for number agreement with **it**, you should say "may terminate a service *worker*" in the singular, not "workers".

Comment: Which of the two handles the event, the user agent or the service worker?  The referent of **it** is not clear.

Comment: "it" must be the user agent,  for singular/plural reasons.

Comment: @TimR What is the problem with "at"?  I don't see any issue with omitting the "when" (or alternatively "that") and leaving it as implied.

Comment: **A user agent may terminate service workers at any time.** It may: [List 1 and 2]  The sentence is wrong.

Comment: @Nasch:  This is not grammatical:   "At any time you have a headache take two aspirin and call me in the morning."  It is conflating two different phrases, "at any time" and "any time" and they mean different things.

Comment: It isn't  clear (to me) which is handling the event, the service worker or the user agent.  It's like saying "An employer may terminate employees whenever they have nothing to do."  Who is "they" -- the employer or the employees?

Comment: @Lambie The example is from a specialized context where the usual rules of English usage are modified. It's definitely not great English literature, but it makes perfect sense in its proper context. I can't make any sense of your proposed revision.

Comment: The excerpt appears to be perfectly fine for a technical manual, or at least it's a common style. Sentence fragments like these seem to be considered a good way to parcel out information in that kind of writing. It's a matter of context. I wouldn't recommend this style for the essay section of an examination, and I'm grateful my job doesn't require me to write like this.

Comment: @DavidK I work with a lot of technical text with colons and lists/bullet points. Usually, **one can find a verb or auxiliary that will go with all of them**. Then, the list/bullet points start with a noun OR main verb Here I all I could think of was: It may: 1) Not have an event to handle 2) Detect abnormal etc. Maybe you can think of a better way. That said, this is typical handling of this kind of thing in formal literature about an issue/product/situation.

Comment: That said, one would never leave an "it" at the end especially since it makes no sense at all in the OP's sentence.

Comment: @DavidK Sure, it can all be rewritten countless ways. I was just explaining how a colon **can be used** if needed. And I repeat, it is standard to have a verb at the end of a sentence followed by bullet points. Another example. /This method can be used for cleaning: 1)  cars or 2) sidewalks./ I am not responsible for the sense of the paragraph, only my explanation of a **typical way** of handling colons and bullet lists.

Comment: Here's the full scoop on this idea: https://tjwithers.com/2022/03/07/punctuation-in-bullet-points-and-numbered-lists/#:~:text=If%20you're%20using%20a,and%E2%80%9D%20(see%20below).

Comment: @Lambie The passage certain violates that person's style manual. They may have a different one. Or none. That's beyond the scope of this question, I think.

Comment: Can you first re-phrase 'A colon lists out multiple incomplete sentences…' so it's at least a Question?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Thanks for your suggestion. I have updated the title, and I wonder if it would be better.

Comment: Thanks and that makes the idea more clear, though the first was better English.

Since it is more clear, please remember lists are special. Like headlines, captions and a very few other cases they do not, and do not need to, follow normal rules of grammar or punctuation.

Yes, the sentence before the colon is incomplete, and it's followed by a list containing incomplete sentences but since it is a list, there can be no general question of correct punctuation.

In such cases all that matters is style, the choice lying first with the organisation and then with the author.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The colon isn't particularly useful there, so you could follow the rule "if in doubt leave it out". But, on the other hand, it doesn't harm understanding or reading. Some style guides might require that the introduction be a complete clause, and that would be another possible edit.

But this native speaker would be happy to read the list with, without or edited to say "... in the following situations:"  If a style guide considers it an error, it is such a minor error that I'd probably not even notice.

Comment: Yes, I would say that the form is very neat and compact, but I think this kind of typing would be penalized in tests like IELTS and GRE, etc.

Comment: The example reads like a technical specification to guide implementation. It could help to clarify whether the conditions are alternatives or must all be met. For instance, "X may terminate Y when: X is in this state; [or] X is in this other state; or Y is in this state." That is, I'd state a subject in each time (unless they're all the same), separate the items with a semicolon, and include "and" or "or" in at least the last item to indicate which condition or conditions must be met.

Comment: It seems clear enough to me that the bulleted list is meant to be read as a parallel construction: "A user agent may terminate service workers at any time it has no event to handle or detects abnormal operation: ... ." The colon is just a typical way of setting off a bulleted list. The problem in this example is not that the punctuation is bad or that the grammar is ambiguous; the problem, I believe, is the subject matter.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, a sentence ending with a bulleted list is treated like the sentence in your other question, and is punctuated similarly. The bulleted list is used to make the structure more visible.

> A user agent may terminate service workers at any time it:
>
> - has no event to handle, or
> - detects abnormal operation: such as infinite loops and tasks exceeding imposed time limits (if any) while handling the events.

(Replace "or" with "and" if that's the intended way the bullet points should be considered together.)

Another option is to make the bullet items complete sentences, explaining the relationship in the introduction to the list:

> A user agent may terminate service workers in any of the following circumstances:
>
> - It has no events to handle.
> - It detects abnormal operation, such as infinite loops and tasks exceeding imposed time limits (if any) while handling the events.

Comment: I wouldn't remove the first colon, I've always seen it in technical manuals and it's meant to be some sort of if/elseif style where the original sentence basically continues as if it's been copied before every bullet.

Comment: The point is to find a way to avoid repeating the "it".

Comment: @DavidK While we wouldn't use the comma when writing `A or B` in a linear sentence, it feels weird to omit it in a bullet item, even though there are only two items.

Comment: @Barmar Bullet lists are fundamentally weird anyway, so I really can't object to your punctuation. I think it also depends on what kind of document you're writing, and I suspect there are various distinct style guides for those who use style guides.

Comment: Indeed. I'm not even sure if this specialized style issue is on-topic for ELL.